# How to filter a dimension based on RLS applied to another dimension?

Tags: powerbi, dax, row-level-security

Assume I have 3 dimension tables and 1 fact table.

DimUser

DimClients

DimCompany

FactSales

All the dims have a 1:M relation with filter flowing from the 1 -> M side.

The Microsoft documentation on RLS shows how to create RLS for one dimension table, and that filters the fact table. But I can't seem to find a way to filter the other dimensions.

Assume I have configured RLS filter on DimUser (`[Username] = USERNAME()`) so that the user of the report can see his own data based on email address, so user can see his own record entry in DimUser. Thus it will auto filter the FactSales also, effectively the user will be able to see only his sales.

However the user can see all clients and companies in the slicer. I want to setup filter on the DimClients and DimCompany so that the user can see only clients and conpanies for which he has made sales. How can I achieve this?

For example:

1. How to apply RLS to the DimClients and DimCompany so that it will filter only those ClientIds that appear in the sales table based on dynamic filter `[Username] = USERNAME()` applied on the DimUsers table?
2. The other option is to enable bidirectional filtering but this is not allowed for multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a measure that looks like this:

```
UserFlag =
CONTAINSSTRING (
    CONCATENATEX ( FactSales, RELATED ( DimUsers[UserEmail] ), "," ),
    USERNAME()
)
```

Create your RLS role and add this filter to each dimension.

```
[UserFlag] = True()
```

The result:  If a row from a dimension is related to a fact row that is in turn related to the DimUser row whose email matches USERNAME(), then the measure returns 'True.'  And so RLS is filtering only to those rows.

Comment: Is there any reason to add the rls to fact table? Adding it to dimension table should auto filter the fact table- isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Putting in on the fact is overkill

Comment: Also, are you asking to create a calculated field or a measure?

Comment: This is definitely a measure. The USERNAME() and USERPRINCIPALNAME() functions can't be used in calculated columns.

Comment: I am thinking about whether it is possible to do like this: rls filter for DimClients should be -> =clientid IN (list of ClientIds from fact table based on username filter on DimUser table). Can this be done.

Comment: @variable, that would be another question.  By all means, give it a try and post if you have difficulties with your new approach.  In the meantime, if please consider upvoting this solution if it has provided some value to you, and accepting it as the solution if it adequately addresses the problem you've posed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CC in your dimension to check if a client has sales associated with the current user.

```
ClientVisible = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('FactSales'), 
    USERELATIONSHIP('FactSales'[ClientId], 'DimClients'[ClientId]),
    FILTER('DimUser', [Username] = USERNAME())
) > 0
```

Also,I would go for creating a CC that filters companies based on whether there are sales records in FactSales related to the current user.

```
[CompanyVisible] = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('FactSales'), 
    USERELATIONSHIP('FactSales'[CompanyId], 'DimCompany'[CompanyId]),
    FILTER('DimUser', [Username] = USERNAME())
) > 0
```

Even if you cannot use the CC in RLS, I can say it still represents the logic you need to implement.
If you share some data, I can dig more on what you want to achieve.

---

Update :

```
ClientIDsForCurrentUser = 
CALCULATETABLE(
    DISTINCT('FactSales'[ClientId]),
    FILTER(
        'FactSales',
        'FactSales'[UserId] IN SELECTCOLUMNS(
            FILTER('DimUser', 'DimUser'[Username] = USERNAME()),
            "UserId", 'DimUser'[UserId]
        )
    )
)
```

The CALCULATETABLE will generate a table of unique ClientIds filtered by the current UserId. Then, the FILTER is applied to ensure that only sales records associated with the current user identified by USERNAME() are included.

Comment: Is this more efficient compared to maybe building a list of clientid and then using IN to filter.

Comment: The solution I provided is conceptual and I intended to illustrate the logic you might want to implement for RLS.
However PBI doesn't support using measures directly in RLS expressions nor calculated columns in the way I described.
RLS requires more straightforward expressions that filter rows based on static/session-based rule without the direct use of CALCULATE functions or relationships.

Comment: What you said can be efficient , if you can pre-calculate this list in a way that Power BI supports within RLS rules. In other words, you creatie a table or column that directly maps users to their allowed ClientIds/CompanyIds  and then implement RLS rules that use this mapping

Comment: No I meant creating that ID table using CALCULATEATABLE, FILTER; but I'm not having the clarity on how to write this DAX.

Comment: @variable try my idea that I implemented as a calculated table.

Comment: To place this into the RLS filter, should I make it `ClientIDsForCurrentUser IN`?